# NVDA not announcing all text inside a role="alert" on Firefox

Tags: windows, firefox, accessibility, nvda

I have a div with `role="alert"` added to the DOM when a form is submitted, it contains a `h3` and a description. At the moment of picking a choice, both texts are announced by VoiceOver (Apple), but using NVDA on Firefox (Win10) only the description text is announced, and the `h3` text is never heard. What might be the problem here?

[image]

Comment: Please add code as text, not an image. This site doesn't have value if the information isn't recoverable.

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to anything you want announced when the alert opens, let's say we add `id="foo"` to your `<h3>` and `id="bar"` to your description div.

Then add `aria-describedby="foo bar"` to the div with alert role. It should then announce all of these when it opens. (Although it might announce some things more than once, depending on AT, but this is not a WCAG violation).

Answer (score 0):

Without a fiddle this is difficult to diagnose (as stated in a comment an image of your source code means I can't copy paste into a fiddle) but there are a couple of items that stand out.

1. 2 `aria-live` regions within an alert is likely to be the cause of this issue, instead add `aria-live` to the `<div class="block-list">` div.
2. null `id` attributes can sometimes interfere with your accessibility tree so I would inspect those and see what the accessibility tree says is happening. Remove them anyway as you should never have a null `id`. Unlikely but still something to fix.
3. What isn't clear is if both change at the same time. `aria-live` will only read **changes** within NVDA so if the `<h3>` isn't actually updating this may also cause the problem.
4. You might have to change the settings on NVDA, it could be you have a setting enabled that suppresses multiple `aria-live` region announcements that happen at once. Haven't got NVDA on this PC to check but will check this point later.